# Is there going to be Twinview ( or alternative) implemented for nouveau?

Tags: xorg, nvidia, nouveau

as I've had heavy issues with nvidia driver regarding performance of basic X window operations (window moving, resizing, scrolling). I switched to nouveau driver. But I lost the possibility of having dual screen that I had previously thanks to nvidia twinview feature... Anyway I rather have fluent X than dual screen, but having dual screen would be nice, so I'm wondering if there is already an nouveau alternative to nvidia's twinview or if it is going to be implemented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

... I've always been able to configure a dual-screen setup using the *Screens*/*Monitors* dialog wich can be used under the `gnome-control-center` or the *System -> Administration* menu. While using the *Nouveau* drivers. It's only when enabled the restricted (buggy) NVidia drivers that I had to use the `nvidia-xconfig` utility. So what happens when you try to use the default monitor/screen configuration utility?

Comment: wow, they must have implemented it already ... because it's identical to twinview, which wasn't before. Thanks